# Браузер не видит статические файлы, однако они доступны

Tags: python, iis, fastcgi, bottle

Всем привет.

Слепил тестовый Python + Bottle проект в Visual Studio 2015. Работает отлично, все стили и скрипты на месте.
Перенес его на старенькую Windows Server 2003 + IIS6 + FastCGI. Проект заработал, но браузер не видит статические файлы, а если их попытаться открыть по ссылке, то они не открываются, а сразу скачиваются.

Почему так происходит?

фрагмент лога:

```
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status 
2017-08-22 22:23:34 W3SVC137267990 10.223.64.2 GET / - 80 - 10.216.46.183 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/43.0.2357.134+Safari/537.36 200 0 0
2017-08-22 22:23:34 W3SVC137267990 10.223.64.2 GET /static/content/bootstrap.min.css - 80 - 10.216.46.183 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/43.0.2357.134+Safari/537.36 304 0 0
2017-08-22 22:23:35 W3SVC137267990 10.223.64.2 GET /static/scripts/bootstrap.js - 80 - 10.216.46.183 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/43.0.2357.134+Safari/537.36 304 0 0
2017-08-22 22:23:35 W3SVC137267990 10.223.64.2 GET /static/scripts/respond.js - 80 - 10.216.46.183 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/43.0.2357.134+Safari/537.36 304 0 0
2017-08-22 22:23:35 W3SVC137267990 10.223.64.2 GET /static/content/site.css - 80 - 10.216.46.183 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/43.0.2357.134+Safari/537.36 304 0 0
2017-08-22 22:23:35 W3SVC137267990 10.223.64.2 GET /static/scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js - 80 - 10.216.46.183 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/43.0.2357.134+Safari/537.36 304 0 0
2017-08-22 22:23:35 W3SVC137267990 10.223.64.2 GET /static/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js - 80 - 10.216.46.183 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/43.0.2357.134+Safari/537.36 304 0 0
```

[image: Здесь стили не работают]

[image: Здесь стили работают]

На верхнем скрине заголовки IIS, с нерабочими стилями
На нижнем тестовый сервер с рабочими стилями

Comment: Статусы 200 и 304 указывают что браузер "видит" файлы. "Открываться" или скачиваться файлы могут в зависимости от заголовков в ответе (сравните присылаемые заголовки в рабочей/нерабочей конфигурациях — в браузер заголовки ответа посмотрите)

Comment: Хорошо, а как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если не знаете как посмотреть http заголовки ответа в браузере XYZ, то задайте отдельный вопрос (если этого ещё никто не сделал)

Comment: Посмотрел, но ничего подозрительного не увидел. (скрины прикрепил к сообщению)

Comment: Вас интересуют "Response headers" (на картинке не хватает Content-type — его следует установить). Интересные заголовки имеют значения в ascii диапазоне здесь, поэтому лучше как текст вместо картинки в вопрос добавить, в общем случае, чтобы легче было найти вопрос людям с похожей проблемой (просто мышкой выделите и перетащите в форму с правкой вопроса, нажав на `{}` кнопку для форматирования в конце).

Comment: Разобрался :) Дело было в функции, которая дает доступ к статическим файлам. Обычно я не указывал аргумент с MIME типом, а в данном случае его пришлось указать.

Comment: Если думаете что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его как свой ответ — [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)